# Get height and width from image in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make an info block on my WordPress website I am working on. 
I want to get the height X width of the photo:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url()
```

I want it printed out on the page something like:

```
image size: 1234x123 1.2mb
```

I just don't know how to make it. I have tried a lot of different examples I found on the web but I always get different errors.

Hope someone has an idea of a good way to do this. :)

Comment: I guess that you can select the image with jquery, and print the attributes?

Comment: or use plain javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This WP function  `wp_get_attachment_image_src`, provides image width and height:

Read here more: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

From docs, it says that it Returns:

> **Returns an array (url, width, height, is_intermediate), or false,
>   if no img.**

**For Example:**

```
  $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), "full" );
```

Now

```
$url = $img[0];
$width = $img[1];
$height = $img[2];
```

Comment: I think that he wants the natural height and width- not the themes 'full' size?

Comment: @Stender 'Full' means image's natural width and height not theme specific size.  i.e. the_post_thumbnail('full');            // Original image resolution (unmodified) src: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: @LinusKarlsson Great! Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Stender My pleasure :) Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5323892/mohsin @mohsin This only works for the first image in the loop, not for each image.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    $size = getimagesize(get_the_post_thumbnail_url());
?>
```

and then echo out the size

```
<?php
    echo $size;
?>
```

taken from the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: I get this error then:
Warning: getimagesize(http://www.website.com/assets/uploads/Flower.jpeg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Comment: Looks like I was too late, this error is due to not having http:// in the url that is being served

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    //thumbnail
                    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),"thumbnail"); //thumbnail,medium,large,full,array(1234,123)
                    //medium
                    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),"medium");
                    //large
                    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),"large"); 
                    //full
                    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),"full"); 
                    //fixed size image(width, height)
                    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),array(1234,123)); 

                }
```